# Django show name of reference not id

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-queryset, relationship

this simple database i created

[image: img]

then this my code for showing the data in view.py

```
    ...
    def get (request, photo_id)
    
    tag = PhotoTag.objects \
           .values('tag_id') \
           .filter(photo_id = photo_id) \
           .all()

    context  = {
            ...
            'my_tag': tag
}
```

and this is in my template

```
{% for data in my_tag %}
    {{ my_tag.tag_id }}
{% endfor %}
```

the result is number, what I need is showing the data of another table (tag table) like
`my_tag => tag_id => name (of another table)`

when I do another way in view.py like

```
tag = PhotoTag.objects \
           .values('tag_id') \
           .filter(photo_id = photo_id) \
           .all()

for data in tag:
       tag_name = Tag.objects \
           .values('name') \
           .filter(id=data.get('tag_id')) \

context = {
     ...,
     'my_tag': tag_name,
}
```

then in template

```
{% for data in my_tag %}
     {{ my_tag.name }}
{% endfor %}
```

the result is what I need (showing the text name of references table) but it's only 1 data, it's not perfectly loop

So Can someone help me solve this problem, or have a magic trick for solve it?

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

View

```
photo_tags = PhotoTag.objects.filter(photo_id=photo_id).values('tag_id')

context = {'photo_tags': photo_tags}
```

Template:

```
{% for photo_tag in photo_tags %}
    {% photo_tag.tag_id.name %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe all you need to do is correct the line where you're filtering the PhotoTag model to generate the queryset.

View:

```
photo_tags = PhotoTag.objects.filter(photo_id=photo_id)

context = {'photo_tags': photo_tags}
```

This should give you a set of all PhotoTag objects that match the given id

Then in your template:

```
{% for pt in photo_tags %}
    {% pt.tag_id.name %}
{% endfor %}
```

Once you have the set of all PhotoTags matching your given id, you can loop through the set in your template and grab any fields you want from the PhotoTag object.